# awk to print values based on sorting the date

Tags: date, awk

I have following info from input of a file.
Using below awk command i have extracted all the ID's but i need only the ID's which has the corresponding time created 30 days older.
I mean, today is Sep 2 2014.
I need to print all the ID's have created 30 days before or older.

```
awk '{print $1}' input.txt

424a5982-9e18-7571-1d0a-e2ca62f9ba99     04/10/14 17:21:08
bbe9c5e2-9efa-7571-1140-eabe581b4a50     04/10/14 20:03:16
3ef42012-9e0c-7571-0673-a293c5b4b23a     04/10/14 17:12:33
5e214312-c593-7571-0cc9-e09b3d2c23c2     04/15/14 17:56:05
6f2324f2-c505-7571-0291-c59240866216     04/15/14 16:14:29
fe9d3a22-c506-7571-1efc-be8e4a2e7a58     04/15/14 16:15:37
fbcd7512-e205-7575-0061-ba76ec55e4db     08/27/14 16:19:11
aeba1362-e9b6-7575-08ed-bbfce30fbaff     08/28/14 15:48:26
f0eb63d2-e9b9-7575-14b6-af2f9d1b8f8b     08/28/14 15:50:45
271417a2-0ead-7576-13a3-a3e07896ef01     09/02/14 08:41:57
51505382-45d8-7573-10b0-f253593051b4     06/03/14 15:34:12
86bc1162-aa70-7573-0bc1-d4599ef344c0     06/16/14 10:48:22
acbd0942-0eb5-7576-0097-f139dd859f4c     09/02/14 08:48:03
c06f1552-4237-7575-1ec9-a5e09355f701     08/07/14 08:14:31
c60d6202-bb49-7571-1c26-c87e822b9075     04/14/14 11:45:24
d8be5b52-bbeb-7571-08cf-826a5aa63894     04/14/14 12:26:56
99e70ee2-2e9c-7571-0eed-eece01cdb38c     03/27/14 12:51:39
```

Comment: Are your dates always more recent than Jan 1 2000? Since your year is in YY instead of YYYY format, you need to determing which century it's in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like this, using GNU awk for time functions:

```
$ gawk -F'[[:space:]/:]+' 'mktime("20"$4" "$2" "$3" "$5" "$6" "$7) < (systime() - 30*24*60*60)' file
424a5982-9e18-7571-1d0a-e2ca62f9ba99     04/10/14 17:21:08
bbe9c5e2-9efa-7571-1140-eabe581b4a50     04/10/14 20:03:16
3ef42012-9e0c-7571-0673-a293c5b4b23a     04/10/14 17:12:33
5e214312-c593-7571-0cc9-e09b3d2c23c2     04/15/14 17:56:05
6f2324f2-c505-7571-0291-c59240866216     04/15/14 16:14:29
fe9d3a22-c506-7571-1efc-be8e4a2e7a58     04/15/14 16:15:37
51505382-45d8-7573-10b0-f253593051b4     06/03/14 15:34:12
86bc1162-aa70-7573-0bc1-d4599ef344c0     06/16/14 10:48:22
c60d6202-bb49-7571-1c26-c87e822b9075     04/14/14 11:45:24
d8be5b52-bbeb-7571-08cf-826a5aa63894     04/14/14 12:26:56
99e70ee2-2e9c-7571-0eed-eece01cdb38c     03/27/14 12:51:39
```

Note that that uses 30 * the number of seconds in a day and compares it to the current date+time to the second, so it works on date+time rather than just date. If that's not what you want, think about it, read the gawk man page, try to modify it yourself (hint replace the time from your input with a specific TOD and use mktime on todays date for the same TOD), and come back if you have specific questions.

Comment: Much thanks, could you please help me understand how this works mktime("20"$4" "$2" "$3" "$5" "$6" "$7)

Comment: Certainly, see http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Time-Functions. If you're going to be doing more text manipulation you should get the book Effective Awk Programming, Third Edition by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have got some understanding on how the mktime and systime function works. But in this case, I am little bit hard to understand this 'mktime("20"$4" "$2" "$3" "$5" "$6" "$7) < (systime() - 30*24*60*60

Comment: Can you provide any more information on what it is you're struggling to understand? mktime() takes a date+time in a specific format and returns the associated number of seconds since the epoch. So given any input date format you need to convert it to the format mktime() expects - that's what I'm doing by concatenating those small string segments, for example with $4 being your year in YY format and so getting 20 prepended to it to make it YYYY format. systime() returns the current secs since the epoch. 30*24*60*60 is the number of seconds in 30 days. Where am I losing you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the systime() and strftime() AWK functions to get the timestamp 30 days ago and compare with the second and third fields.

The most suitable procedure may be:

1. Get the date and time for 30 days ago in the format YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS [ Use the systime() and strftime() functions ]
2. Resort the second field to look the YYYY-MM-DD format  [ Use substr() function ]
3. Compare every timestamp (new second field and third field) with the 30-day-ago timestamp [ String comparison ].

Best regards

P.D: the "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS" timestamp format (or any other similar) is very suitable for timestamp comparisons when only string check functions are available.

Comment: I find hard to code it. If you know please code it and let me know the output.

Comment: Yes, user3834663, the code was the only thing you were looking for.